# AWS Lambda: "Check the console logs for details. Message: The quota has been exceeded."

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

First, I got this error when I tried to edit the lambda function in the Lambda console editor:

> Check the console logs for details. Message: The quota has been exceeded.

Later, the Lambda function($Latest) stopped loading in the editor, it hangs at "loading your lambda function.." message.

I have used only half of the AWS Lambda code storage. Suddenly that error popped up when I was editing the function.

What is this error about and where can I get console logs?

Comment: You can check the logs in AWS CloudWatch https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-functions-logs.html

Comment: The hanging is probably unrelated. I've seen the editor spin forever. I close the file then open it again from the hierarchy and it works okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered this issue recently and when you get a chance you can review the three suggestions which assisted me in resolving this issue :

1. For lambda functions with assigned memory of 128 MB, found out that increasing the assigned memory assisted in resolving this issue.
2. Clearing the browser cache and cookies also assisted in resolving this issue.
3. The last work-around, involves :

   - Right clicking on the Lambda code editor and selecting **'Reload frame'** or try in another browser with new profile (e.g private mode or incognito mode)